# Can't get rid of ’ from pandas text dataframe despite using 'string replace' and 'remove punctuations'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, data-wrangling

I am cleaning a text dataframe that has a lot of junk values. I did all necessary wrangling steps including 'removed punctuations'
However, i still see `’`

I applied this to remove punctuations

```
def remove_punctuation(s):
    s = ''.join([i for i in s if i not in frozenset(string.punctuation)])
    return s

df['question_text'] = df['question_text'].apply(remove_punctuation)
```

It didn't get rid of those thick quotes

Also, did the following:

```
import string
df['question_text'].str.replace('[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '')
```

AND

```
df['question_stemmed'].str.replace('’', '')
```

No luck.

Top 4 bigram words in the dataframe by number of occurences are as follows. Having such junk quotes in the dataframe despite having removed punctuations as stated in above steps is not helping with my data cleaning step. Can someone advise what is wrong and why those thick quotes are not going away?

```
| Word     | Frequency |
|----------|-----------|
| best way | 5559      |
| ’ s      | 5136      |
| ’ t      | 3724      |
| this will| 3724      |
```

Comment: The key insight from the duplicate question is that you need to assign back to the column; `.replace` just creates a separate Series.

Comment: gosh...such a trivial miss.. thanks @KarlKnechtel